# Reuse selector in SCSS as suffix

Tags: css, sass

How can I use the ampersand in SCSS to reuse the parent selector as suffix?

I came from LESS CSS and are doing my first project in SCSS right now. In LESS I could use the ampersand `&` to reference the parent selector at any point in a selector. I seems to me like this operator has some quirks in SCSS.

Example:

```
.grid {
    /* grid styles */

    ul& {
        /* grid styles if this class was set to an UL element */
    }
}
```

In LESS CSS this compiles to the following and this is what I need in most cases:

```
.grid {
    /* grid styles */
}
ul.grid {
    /* grid styles if this class was set to an UL element */
}
```

But in SCSS this throws an exception. There is another notation in SCSS looking like this:

```
.grid {
    /* grid styles */

    ul#{&} {
        /* using SCSS escaping syntax*/
    }
}
```

But this again gives me the unexpected result of:

```
.grid {
    /* grid styles */
}
.grid ul.grid {
    /* Uh SCCS, what happened now? */
}
```

Is there a way in SCSS to **reuse the parent selector when it is not the first part of a selector**?

Comment: @Vucko `ul &` does work, but results in a complete different selector…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `@at-root` directive to produce a rule that is generated outside its definition scope but that retains the value of its parent (`&`)

```
.grid {

    /* grid styles */

    @at-root {

        ul#{&} {
            /* using SCSS escaping syntax*/
        }
    }
}
```

---

Output

```
.grid {
  /* grid styles */
}

ul.grid {
  /* using SCSS escaping syntax*/
}
```

---

Tested on sassmeister

[image]

Further information on [SASS documentation page](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#at-root)

Comment: Are you sure? This throws an error in sassmeister. (`ul#{": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "&} {`) Maybe I misconfigured it.

Comment: I tried it in sassmeister, I copied and pasted the output from there

Comment: My bad. Excuse me, this seems to work from 3.4.9+.